# My register form from laravel is bringing a database error with phpmyadmin columns.Please help me solve this issue

Tags: controller, migration

I am getting this error in my registration form in the web browser.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where 
clause' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `users` where `0` in 
(mojay9905@gmail.com, 123) limit 1)
```

This is my register controller code:

```
your text
```

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //validation
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name'=> 'required|max:255',`
        'username'=> 'required|max:255',
        'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email|max:255',
       'password'=>'required|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I don't know if the  problem is in my migration table or the controller